# How to extract the number with decimal in Hive using regexp_extract

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

I have a column is event_list. So I would like to extract the number after `20220=`. The value would contain `.`, but i could only get the value before `.`.

My current query is

```
regexp_extract(event_list, '20220=([0-9]+)', 1)
```

The event_list column is like
[image]

Comment: change it to `'20220=([0-9]+\.[0-9]+),'` .. if there will always be a decimal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
hive> select regexp_extract(',211,253,20219,20220=27.87,20222,20223','20220=([^,]*)',1);

27.87
```

or

```
hive> select regexp_extract(',211,253,20219,20220=27.87,20222,20223','20220=(.*?),',1);

27.87
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using :-

```
regexp_extract(event_list,'20220=([0-9.]+)', 1)
```

if you want data after `,` also then use it also in the regex expression like below:-

```
regexp_extract(event_list,'20220=([0-9.,]+)', 1)
```

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!

Comment: Thanks ... Accept the answer if it helps you for future reference.